# Node.js form plugin similar to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, node.js, plugins

As the title states, I'm looking for a some kind of form plugin in Node.js that will allow me to create forms in a manner similar to Rails.  I've come across several Node.js form plugins, with the closest one being [Formed](https://github.com/arbarlow/formed).  However, that plugin is specific to Sequelize (I am using JugglingDB).

Ideally, it would be nice to do something similar to the following (assuming EJS):

```
<%- form_for(user, function(form) { %>
    <%- form.input('username') %>
    <%- form.input('password') %>
    <%- form.submit() %>
<%- }) %>
```

with output similar to the following:

```
<form action="/users" method="post" id="new_user_form">
    <div class="input required">
        <label for="user_username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_username" id="new_user_form_user_username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input required">
        <label for="user_password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="user_password" id="new_user_form_user_password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="user_submit" value="Create User"/>
</form>
```

The only other plugin I've come across that seems to have some sort of following and recent updates is [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).  Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't have anything to do with the rendering of forms, just the processing of forms.

Answer (score 1):

See [caolan / forms on GitHub](https://github.com/caolan/forms/).